# Getting error "'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses does not support availability zones at location 'japanwest " while creating azurerm_public_ip

Tags: terraform, azure-resource-manager

I am using terraform to create public ip in azure but getting below error and in the same region I am able to create it using UI :

```
Error: creating/updating Public Ip Address: (Name "dev-hub-agw1-pip1" / Resource Group "dev-iapi"): network.PublicIPAddressesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="LocationNotSupportAvailabilityZones" Message="The resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/dev-hub-agw1-pip1' does not support availability zones at location 'japanwest'."
│ 
│   with module.app-gateway.azurerm_public_ip.agw,
│   on ../modules/app-gateway/main.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_public_ip" "agw":
│   14: resource "azurerm_public_ip" "agw" {
```

Here is the code

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "iapi-agw-ip" {
  name                = "${var.env}-iapi-agw-ip"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  availability_zone   = "No-Zone"
}
```

Comment: Hello @so9868, may i know what is the azurerm version you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use latest ***`azurerm`*** version and ***`terraform`*** version. As I tested your code in the same location and it got successfully deployed.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "iapi-agw-ip" {
  name                = "ansuman-iapi-agw-ip"
  location            = "japanwest"
  resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  availability_zone   = "No-Zone"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Latest ***Terraform Version*** - `v1.1.2` and latest ***Azurerm Provider Version*** - `v2.90.0`.